# Clojurescript and Google Closure: How to correctly require a namespace or import a class?

Tags: clojurescript

I noticed in the tut [Clojurescript 101](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/11/07/clojurescript-101/) that you can use closure classes like:

```
(ns async-tut1.core
  (:import [goog.net XhrIo]))
```

But there is a note that says:

> Note: import is only for this use case, you never use it with ClojureScript libraries

What does it really mean? As I understand it, you should not import classes this way. Am I correct? If I am, how would you do it then? Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to import the Closure classes, you use import, if you are importing functions or vars, then you use require or use:

```
(ns async-tut1.core
  (:require [goog.events :refer [listen] :as ev])
  (:import [goog.net XhrIo]))
```

What it means is that the `import` form is specific to the use case of importing classes from the host libraries (google closure modules).